# Complete metric space or not

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$ with Euclidean topology a complete metric space?

I'm quiet sure that it is not, but there is a "yes" answer in my source.

Comment: There are metrics on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$ that induce the standard topology and that make it a complete metric space. It is a completely metrisable space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Euclidean *metric*, your set is not complete: take any Cauchy sequence approaching the origin.

Completeness and Cauchy sequences are not topological notions however. They are properties that you can begin to discuss if you are considering uniform spaces. Metric spaces induce uniformities, just like they induce a topology. Because of this, you can talk about Cauchy sequences in a metric space.

Two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on a set $X$ are called equivalent if they induce the same topology and are called strongly equivalent if there exist two positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that $ad'\leq d\leq bd'$ for all $x,y\in X$. Strongly equivalent metrics also induce the same uniformity and preserve Cauchy sequences.

However there are metrics equivalent to the Euclidean metric that cause your set to become complete, as the comment from @Daniel Fischer points out.

Comment: One such metric is sending the point in $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2-0$ to the point directly above it on the surface $z=1/(x^2+y^2)$. And then taking the standard Euclidean metric in space between the two points. So the complete metric is $d^2((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+(1/[x_1^2+x_2^2]-1/[y_1^2+y_2^2])^2$